# TCP Client working with BeginRead DataReturned is NULL after first Response of given Bytes

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am struggling with the C# TCP Client BeginRead Method.

I am communicating with a machine as Server.

Since the machine sends push packets when a button is pressed, I need to listen all the time.
I am doing that asynchronously via BeginRead(..).

To the first request sent to the machine (10 Bytes), the Response is correctly read (3 Bytes). If i repeat some other kind of request, the BeginRead just returns an Array of 00 Bytes (Lenght 1024).

The Wireshark Screenshots prove that this is a problem of my c# application.

The Push Messages from the machine aren't working after that second request too.

```
internal void StartRecieveContinuous()
{
    Open();

    int dataLenght = 1024;

    this.LastRecievedData = new byte[dataLenght];

    NetworkStream stream = Client?.GetStream() ?? throw new Exception("The TCP Client wasn't initialized!");

    stream.BeginRead(LastRecievedData, 0, dataLenght, CallbackDataRecieved, stream);

    ListenerRunning = true;
}

private void CallbackDataRecieved(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ListenerRunning = false;

    // Debug
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",this.LastRecievedData.Take(20).Select(x => x.ToString("X"))));
    // Debug

    if((this.LastRecievedData?.Count(x => x > 0) ?? 0) > 0)
    {
        EventDataRecieved?.Invoke(this, new DataRecievedArgs(this.LastRecievedData.Take(this.LastRecievedData?.Length ?? 0).ToArray()));
    }

    StartRecieveContinuous();
}
```

Debug Console Logs (hex):

> 5 1 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (First Response)

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (Second Response)

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (Button Press Event Data)

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (Button Release Event Data)

[image: Request to Maschine]

[image: Response from Machine]

Edit:

I tried using endRead but my problem remains:

```
private void CallbackDataRecieved(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    NetworkStream myNetworkStream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;

    myNetworkStream.EndRead(ar);

    ListenerRunning = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(">>> " + string.Join(" ", this.LastRecievedData.Take(20).Select(x => x.ToString("X"))));

    if((this.LastRecievedData?.Count(x => x > 0) ?? 0) > 0)
    {
        EventDataRecieved?.Invoke(this, new DataRecievedArgs(this.LastRecievedData.Take(this.LastRecievedData?.Length ?? 0).ToArray()));
    }

    StartRecieveContinuous();
}
```

Comment: where is the call to `stream.EndRead`? you *must* call `stream.EndRead` in the callback, and capture the return value

Comment: @MarcGravell to my understanding, calling stream.EndRead triggers the Callback Method of BeginRead as it forces the Reading to Stop. The return-value of EndRead is int only the number of bytes read, not the data itself. Am I wrong with that?

Comment: I think a `stream.EndRead` would do the trick because you create a feedback loop in the callback starting another read. Alternatively I would recommend not refreshing the backing buffer to a new reference every loop, since you are not ending the reading of the stream I believe you might be reading data into the original, now dereferenced buffer, when your callback attempts to start a new `BeginRead`. [You can find info on how to set up this on msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread?view=net-5.0#remarks). Consider making a class holding it.

Comment: @MaxN I'll answer that in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are **required** to call `EndRead` in the callback, and until you do that: you are in undefined behaviour land, attempting to perform multiple overlapped read operations. To clarify: `EndRead` doesn't *cause* the read operation to end; rather: `BeginFoo` and `EndFoo` are simply the two pieces of an async operation of a given pattern, that mirror a synchronous `Foo` call.

You are correct (comments) that `EndRead` simply returns the number of bytes read, but that mirrors exactly with what the non-async `Read` API returns; and similarly, the data is *stored* into the buffer that you passed in. Just like with `Read`, you are also required to **pay attention** to the integer that `EndRead` returns; it is the most important thing you get from a read! You should not attempt to process more than this much data from the buffer your provided.

---

However! There is quite honestly a *lot* of things to pick apart in the code shown - threading, buffer management, sync vs async operations; the TCP APIs are very hard to get write, when used manually. If you're using .NET Core / .NET 5 or above, then honestly: you can move all of this to Kestrel using the "pipelines" API, which deals with *all of this scrappy code for you*, so that all *you* need to write is your protocol code (the actual data parsing/processing code). An overview of this can be found in this [multi-part series](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got the BeginRead/EndRead soltuion to work.

The problem was that I started the BeginRead again when sending a command without checking if it was allready running.

I took a look at these pipelines, but I aint switching right now. Maybe sometime later in the next project.

Thanks guys!